# Why nmap sometimes does not show device name?

Tags: nmap

Executing following command "sudo nmap -sP 123.00.0.00" depending on the network might return:

Nmap scan report for 123.00.0.00
Host is up (0.28s latency).
MAC Address: 84:38:35:XX:XX:XX (Apple)

or (let's assume it's the same IP but different network)

Nmap scan report for **Tomas-Mac-Book** (123.00.0.00)
Host is up (0.28s latency).
MAC Address: 84:38:35:XX:XX:XX (Apple)

I'm guessing this depends on the network settings. Is there a way to get the device name in cases where only IP is returned with the above command?

Answer (score 0):

With the -sP option, NMAP makes a DNS request to resolve the names of the IPS's:

> . By default, Nmap still does reverse-DNS resolution on the hosts to
>   learn their names

From [NMAP Host discovery options](http://nmap.org/book/man-host-discovery.html)

So, if the network DNS is able to resolve the names of the hosts, NMAP returns the network names of each IP.

To avoid this DNS resolution, if you add a 'n', it is disabled so -snP, would never try to make a DNS resolution.